# Configuring rules for Firestore so user only gets records they own

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

This is a followup to this question
[Firestore permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472230/firestore-permissions)

I'm trying to set rules on my firestore

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /analysis/{analysis} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner_uid;
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is
**a.** When doing a list operation only those documents belonging to a user are returned
**b.** only documents a user owns can be read or written by that user.

With the above configuration  **b.** is accomplished.
how do I do accomplish **a.** ?

Comment: you can achieve that client side with a query. i think your first problem is not possible with rules.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remember that firestore rules are not filters, they're a server-side validation of your queries.
You should always make your queries match your rules, or else you'll get permission errors.

In your case you already made the rule to enforce reading/listing on user owned documents. Now you simply have to make the corresponding query with the right filters :

```js
const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

db.collection("analysis").where("owner_uid", "==", userId)
```

Another thing.
With your current rules, your users won't be able to create a new document, only edit an existing one, here are the updated rules to allow that :

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner_uid;

allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner_uid
             || request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner_uid;
```

Comment: Is it possible to restrict access based on filters rather than request.auth?

Comment: @sheerun Do you have an example of what you'd like to achieve ?

Comment: I'ld like to allow users to perform only certain queries

Comment: Thank you for this, I spent a long time looking for this info. Does anyone know where it's explained in the docs?

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot -- also found it in the docs, here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules